# Adding new values to JSON (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I need little help. I'm using Json to save some of my game progress values and everything is working except I'm facing with one issue. When I try to save new values it overrides the old ones but I don't want to override the old values I wanna keep them and add new ones. Can anyone provide little help? I'm using LiTJson, here is the code:

```
 SavedShips savedShips = new SavedShips(shipsCount);
     JsonData data = JsonMapper.ToJson(savedShips);
     File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/ships.json", data.ToString());
```

I tried loading old values and adding new ones something like this:

```
string fromJson = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/ships.json");
data = JsonMapper.ToObject(fromJson);
data.Add(new SavedShips(shipsCount));
File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/ships.json", data.ToString());
```

But got ArgumentException: Unable to wrap the given object with JsonData.
Thanks!

Comment: What is `SavedShips` and what does it do with shipsCount?

Comment: When serializing Json you take an Object and translate it into text, in the format of Json. If you have 1 object, serialize it and overvwrite the previous file you will get just that one object in the file, like you're doing now. What you want to do is to add every ship to a list then serialize the list to json. In your try you never seem to serialize it to json before saving to file?

Comment: I know there is another way to solve this by getting the old values and adding new ones, but for now seems that replacing WriteAllText with AppendAllText solves the issue. Thansk for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use File.AppendText() instead of WriteAllText().

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx

This should add to the end of the file instead of overwriting it.

Comment: You might have some issues if you need to convert the JSON back to an object. If you need to do that, I'd use a separate file for each ship/save. Or, as Fredrik said, use a list instead. Or a third option; write a method for splitting the file before deserializing each object in turn.